# Cordova build android failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing

Tags: cordova

cordova build android is failed, here are requirements command output and error log:

```
cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-23,android-24,android-25
Gradle: installed
```

Error Log:

```
cordova build android

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.397 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

1.- Try opening Android SDK and installing all posible APIs and SDK Tools, update if necessary

2.- Then go to this page, https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads
and download tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip, (or MAC or Linux)

3.- Unzip and replace this folder in /Android/Sdk folder

4.- If problem is not solved, then check if ANDROID_HOME and PATH locations are correct. To do this, write the following:

`export ANDROID_HOME={THE ANDROID SDK PATH}/
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, because I had error in PATH variable.
try to ensure if your path is correct or no by this comment in cmd:

`echo %PATH%`

you need to use these 2 path

> ;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

and you ANDROID_HOME must be:

> C:\your_SDK_Path\Android\sdk